# If Cell has Specific Text then Multiply 3 Cells - Office Pro Plus 2021

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2021

I am trying to make a form where if Column `B` contains "Carcass" or "Benchtop" then Column `H` will show `E * F * G/1000000`

But if it shows Misc or Hardware etc, it will show Column `G`

Otherwise it will return a Blank result if nothing matches.

I've tried multiple different Functions, the most luck I've had was with IF and OR but it doesn't exactly work correctly. This is a function I used that did work until I added more Results to search.

```
=IFS((B4:B20={"Carcass","Benchtop"}),(E4:E20 * F4:F20 * G4:G20)/1000000,
 OR(B4:B20={"Misc","Doors"}),G4:G20)
```

I Don't know if this Helps or not, but Functions :D
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `B4:B20={"Carcass","Benchtop"}` returns 2D array that is why you get `#SPILL!` error.

Something like this would work:

```
=MAP(B4:B20,E4:E20,F4:F20,G4:G20,LAMBDA(b,e,f,g,IF(OR(b={"Carcass","Benchtop"}),e*f*g/1000000,IF(OR(b={"Misc","Doors","Hardware"}),g,""))))
```

[image]

Or

```
=MAP(B4:B20,E4:E20,F4:F20,G4:G20,LAMBDA(b,e,f,g,IF(OR(b={"Carcass","Benchtop"}),e*f*g/1000000,IF(b<>"",g,""))))
```

if you want to do calculation for "Carcass" and "Benchtop", show blank for empty rows and show `G` for every other `B` value than "Carcass", "Benchtop" or blank.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the reply, Unfortunately I don't believe my version of Excel has the MAP or LAMBDA function. I get a #NAME? error.

Comment: @Aloosh you should update tag corresponding to your Excel version. Also you could simply put =IF(OR(B4={"Carcass","Benchtop"}),E4*F4*G4/1000000,IF(B4<>"",G4,"")) in H4 and drag it down

Comment: So I somehow realized my account has access to Office 365, I retried those functions and they all gave me #SPILL? but  =IF(OR(B4={"Carcass","Benchtop"}),E4*F4*G4/1000000,IF(B4<>"",G4,"")) worked for me, but probably not for long as I have more Product Types that will require a different Calculation that I haven't made tables etc for yet.

Example: Carcass and Benchtop are Calculated based on LxWxQuantity
Misc and Hardware Calculated by Quantity,
Polishing Calculated by Linear Meters which I'd need to make a formula for.

Comment: #SPILL error means that formula tries to spill array, but there are values in other cells which prevents from doing that. Clear all H column and then try to add one of those MAP formulas

Answer (score 1):

IFS returns a result for both the array inputs of `{"Carcass","Benchtop"}`.

For instance `=IFS(B4:B8={"Carcass","Benchtop"},1)` returns `1` for the TRUE and an error for the FALSE, because IFS doesn't behave like IF, where we can decline a value in case of FALSE
[image]

Also you use OR on an array, but OR will check any value of the range to return a TRUE (not only in the current row), and will return TRUE for all or FALSE for all.

You can wrap your conditions in MMULT to check for a sum of the boolean and use IF instead of IFS:

```
=IF(MMULT(N(B4:B20={"Carcass","Benchtop"}),{1;1}),
    (E4:E20 * F4:F20 * G4:G20)/1000000,
     IF(MMULT(N(B4:B20={"Misc","Doors"}),{1;1}),
        G4:G20,
        "")
    )
```

[image]

You could also use:

```
=IF((B4:B20="Carcass")+(B4:B20="Benchtop"),
    (E4:E20 * F4:F20 * G4:G20)/1000000,
    IF((B4:B20="Misc")+(B4:B20="Doors"),
       G4:G20,
       "")
    )
```

And as Mayukh commented, if you want to include any non-blanks other than you can use:

`=IF((B4:B20="Carcass")+(B4:B20="Benchtop"),(E4:E20 * F4:F20 * G4:G20)/1000000,IF((B4:B20<>""),G4:G20,""))`

Comment: Your formula (as per your screenshot and my earlier testing as well) produces the calculated result for all rows, notice the 0's and the 1 for 1000*1000*1/10^6 (or the 0 for "Doors"). OP stated they wanted nothing for the ones that didn't match the criteria.

Comment: SUM(N(B4:B20={"Carcass","Benchtop"})) returns one value. If at least one Carcass or Benchtop is in a list, then it is always >0 (true) and other conditions are never checked

Comment: Oops,@Notus_Panda & @user11222393 updated. SUM indeed returns a single value. MMULT will spill.

Comment: @P.b Sir, even `Polishing` should return `1` as OP stated : `But if it shows Misc or Hardware etc, it will show Column G` specifically has mentioned **`etc`**

Comment: I had do some thing like this : `=IF((B4:B20="Carcass")+(B4:B20="Benchtop"),(E4:E20 * F4:F20 * G4:G20)/1000000,IF((B4:B20<>""),G4:G20,""))`

Answer (score 0):

First approach:

```
=SWITCH(TRUE,OR(B4={"Carcass","Benchtop"}),(E4*F4*G4)/1000000,OR(B4<>{"Carcass","Benchtop"}),G4,"")
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(
     n, MMULT(N({"Carcass","Benchtop"}<>B4:B20),{1;1}),
     IF(n=1,(E4:E20*F4:F20*G4:G20)/10^6,IF(n>1,G4:G20,"")))
```

[image: Try Using]